# Can't make getElementById() method working correctly in a java serializer program

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxp

I'm writing an XML serializer with JAXP. I'm receiving pseudo random data from a JAR and I'm building the DOM tree. I have to check if I already inserted the same Element into the tree; in order to perform this control  I'm trying to use the method:

```
Element e = myDocument.getElementById(ao.getId());
if (e == null) {
    // element is not a duplicate
    access.appendChild(authorizationObject);
}else{
    // element already in the tree 
}
```

So, in every Element I create before adding them to the tree I set:

```
ao = a.getAuthorizationObject();
authorizationObject = myDocument.createElement("authorizationobject");
authorizationObject.setAttribute("id", ao.getId());
authorizationObject.setIdAttribute("id", true);
```

It can happen that in the object ao sometimes I get the same element twice (or more).
The problem is that the program *always* enter inside the if instruction.

You can find all the program's code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33459047/StackOverflow/JAXP%20Serializer/AccessSerializer.java) and the DTD [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33459047/StackOverflow/JAXP%20Serializer/access.dtd) for your reference.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for all your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to append the `authorizationObject` to the `access` Element. Your code should be as follows

```
    authorizationObject = myDocument.createElement("authorizationobject");
    authorizationObject.setAttribute("id", ao.getId());

    authorizationObject.setIdAttribute("id", true);     
    System.out.println("AO.ID = " + ao.getId());
    access.appendChild(authorizationObject); 
    // then only this Element will be   appended to the document
    if (myDocument.getElementById(ao.getId()) == null ) {
```

I see that you have finally appended the authorization object to the document. but, it should be done prior to document.getElementById() method call

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the original answer, I edited it now.
I don't want to add another child if already present into the tree. 
If you checked the linked file before it was already implemented as now explained in the answer. Thank you!